# Android facebook button loginfacebook setReadPermissions no action

Tags: android, android-button, android-facebook

I have call LoginButton set permissions.

```
  mBtnLoginFacebook.setFragment(this);
        mBtnLoginFacebook.registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                                           mFacebookCallback);
        mBtnLoginFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile",
                                                           "email",
                                                           "user_birthday"));
```

but in logcat :

```
06-19 16:31:12.427    1592-1592/com.createtrips.app E/>>>>>﹕ accrsss{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, public_profile]}
06-19 16:31:12.647    1592-1592/com.createtrips.app W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for birthday
```

//______________//
Birthday no call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app requests `user_birthday` permission Facebook will have to [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) how your app uses it.

According to the new Facebook Terms And Conditions.